# What built-in options are there for generating HTML from a Rails helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partial-views, view-helpers

In my project I am using HAML. I use a construct similar to the following fragment throughout my project:

```
%a.social.twitter{:href => '...'}
  %span.text Twitter
  %span.twitter-icon
```

I want to write a helper to generate this fragment for me:

```
def social_network(name)
 link_to(...) do
   # generate span.text and span.twitter.icon
 end
end
```

Ideally I don't want to just pass in some HTML disguised in string form to the `link_to` block. I prefer to use a markup builder or an API.

What built-in options does Rails have that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: My advice to you is to try to figure out if you can use a partial instead of a helper (call the partial from the helper instead?). The problem with doing this with a helper is that now you're locking away markup in something that should generally only have logic in it, and it could take a frontend person who's not familiar with rails some time to figure out, instead of seeing it right there in the view folder as a partial. Just my 2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) and [`tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) in `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` which

> Provides methods to generate HTML tags programmatically when you can’t use a Builder.

For example:

```
def social_network(name, klass)
  link_to(...) do
    content_tag(:span, name)
    tag(:span, class: klass)
  end
end
```